# Subset calculation of list of integers

Tags: algorithm, sorting, set, bloom-filter

I'm currently implementing an algorithm where one particular step requires me to calculate subsets in the following way.

Imagine I have sets (possibly millions of them) of integers. Where each set could potentially contain around a 1000 elements:

```
Set1: [1, 3, 7]
Set2: [1, 5, 8, 10]
Set3: [1, 3, 11, 14, 15]
...,
Set1000000: [1, 7, 10, 19]
```

Imagine a particular input set:

```
InputSet: [1, 7]
```

I now want to quickly calculate to which this InputSet is a subset. In this particular case, it should return Set1 and Set1000000.

Now, brute-forcing it takes too much time. I could also parallelise via Map/Reduce, but I'm looking for a more intelligent solution. Also, to a certain extend, it should be memory-efficient. I already optimised the calculation by making use of BloomFilters to quickly eliminate sets to which the input set could never be a subset.

Any smart technique I'm missing out on?

Thanks!

Comment: What language? Do you have sample code?

Comment: Language doesn't really matter (although Java would be preferred). Looking more for a conceptual solution.

Comment: If this is Java, `Set` already has `.containsAll()`, I suppose you have tried this? Or do you really wish to avoid builtin solutions? Also, are your sets always sorted?

Comment: Yeah. But I do not want to execute a million containsAll operations. I would like to easily and quickly identify potential subsets. Sets can assumed to be sorted.

Comment: Well, you said you already filtered out unmatching sets using a bloom filter, so...

Comment: What is the range/domain of the elements in the sets? What is the cardinality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well - it seems that the bottle neck is the number of sets, so instead of finding a set by iterating all of them, you could enhance performance by mapping from elements to all sets containing them, and return the sets containing all the elements you searched for.

This is very similar to what is done in AND query when searching the [inverted index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_index) in the field of [information retrieval](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_retrieval).

In your example, you will have:

```
1 -> [set1, set2, set3, ..., set1000000]
3 -> [set1, set3]
5 -> [set2]
7 -> [set1, set7]
8 -> [set2]
...
```

**EDIT:**

In inverted index in IR, to save space we sometimes use *d-gaps* - meaning we store the offset between documents and not the actual number. For example, `[2,5,10]` will become `[2,3,5]`. Doing so and using [delta encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_encoding) to represent the numbers tends to help a lot when it comes to space.

(Of course there is also a downside: you need to read the entire list in order to find if a specific set/document is in it, and cannot use binary search, but it sometimes worths it, especially if it is the difference between fitting the index into RAM or not).

Comment: I was thinking along the same line (inverted index). The only downside is that it roughly doubles the amount of required memory to do the processing. Was hoping for something more memory efficient ...

Comment: You could compress the index by hashing the keys in the inverted index and allowing for collisions, trading some memory for computation. As an extreme example, you could index by the least significant bit, so you have a list of sets containing odd numbers, and another list of sets containing even numbers.

Comment: And now that I think about this more, isn't what I'm proposing equivalent to a bloom filter?

Comment: @user1943042 Do you need to know what the original sets are very often? If not, you could just not store them at all (and now you haven't doubled your memory usage), and now recovering the original sets becomes the problem you are trying to solve now.

Comment: @PhilFrost: It does resemble it. Also, an optimization that is often used in inverted index in IR is storing only the *offset* (for example `[2,5,10]` will become `[2,3,5]`). This is called *d-gaps* For sparse data, by doing so and using [delta encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_encoding) for representing the numbers tend to help a lot.

Comment: I gave an answer that is an alternative this this that should solve at least some of the issues with it.

Answer (score 0):

How about storing a list of the sets which contain each number?

```
1 -- 1, 2, 3, 1000000
3 -- 1, 3
5 -- 2
etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Start searching from biggest number (7) of input set and
   eliminate other subsets (Set1 and Set1000000 will returned).
2. Search other input elements  (1) in remaining sets.

Answer (score 0):

Extending amit's solution, instead of storing the actual numbers, you could just store intervals and their associated sets.

For example using a interval size of 5:

```
 (1-5): [1,2,3,1000000]
 (6-10): [2,1000000]
 (11-15): [3]
 (16-20): [1000000]
```

In the case of (1,7) you should consider intervals (1-5) and (5-10) (which can be determined simply by knowing the size of the interval). Intersecting those ranges gives you [2,1000000]. Binary search of the sets shows that indeed, (1,7) exists in both sets.

Though you'll want to check the min and max values for each set to get a better idea of what the interval size should be. For example, 5 is probably a bad choice if the min and max values go from 1 to a million.

You should probably keep it so that a binary search can be used to check for values, so the subset range should be something like (min + max)/N, where 2N is the max number of values that will need to be binary searched in each set. For example, "does set 3 contain any values from 5 to 10?" this is done by finding the closest values to 5 (3) and 10 (11), in this case, no it does not. You would have to go through each set and do binary searches for the interval values that could be within the set. This means ensuring that you don't go searching for 100 when the set only goes up to 10.

You could also just store the range (min and max). However, the issue is that I suspect your numbers are going be be clustered, thus not providing much use. Although as mentioned, it'll probably be useful for determining how to set up the intervals.

It'll still be troublesome to pick what range to use, too large and it'll take a long time to build the data structure (1000 * million * log(N)). Too small, and you'll start to run into space issues. The ideal size of the range is probably such that it ensures that the number of set's related to each range is approximately equal, while also ensuring that the total number of ranges isn't too high.

Edit:
One benefit is that you don't actually need to store all intervals, just the ones you need. Although, if you have too many unused intervals, it might be wise to increase the interval and split the current intervals to ensure that the search is fast. This is especially true if processioning time isn't a major issue.